# How to quickly read setup table with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a "setup" table on MySQL with 4 columns:

```
ID|Variable|Value |Description
-------------------------------
1 |setting1|value1|Description1
2 |setting2|value2|Descritpion2
3 |setting3|value3|Description3
```

etc ...

I need to extract every setting and with it, create a variable (with the same name of the setting) assign it the corresponding Value.
For example

```
echo $setting1;
```

should return: value1

and so on

This should avoid huge number of queries like

```
SELECT * FROM setup WHERE Variable LIKE 'setting1'
```

I did try things like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM setup";
$sth = $sql->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $$row[Variable] = $row[Value];
    echo $setting1;
}
```

but it returns nothing

Is there any way to get it, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your loop. Index should be in quotes. try following code:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ${$row["Variable"]} = $row["Value"];
    echo $setting1;
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($row)` inside while?

Comment: array(4) { 
["ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
["Variable"]=> string(2) "setting1"
["Value"]=> string(1) "value1" 
["Description"]=> string(4) "Description1" 
} etc ...

Comment: Then this code must work. Have you added `{}` around `$row["Variable"]`?

Comment: Sorry it works now. I did forget (sorry for that) the lines you suggested, internally to a foreach() that was suggested by the other colleague before (I don't see any longer his answer).
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Its okay. glad to help @TormyVanCool